# Conditions to rule out the existence of a non-zero function vanishing on every closed fibre

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes. For every closed point $s\in S$, there is a closed fibre $X_s\to X$ over $s$. Intuitively, it is quite natural to claim that $f\in\mathcal O(X)$ is zero iff $f|_{X_s}=0$ for every closed $s\in S$.

However I know it is not true in general. A counter-example is for $X=S=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ with $A$ a commutative ring with nonzero nilpotent radical.

Under strong conditions such as that $S=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ for some field, we have that vanishing on every closed fibre implies that the function is zero. However this is too strong.

I want to ask for some conditions on $X\to S$ such that the intuitive claim is true. I am mainly interested when $S$ is a affine (irreducible) $\mathbb C$-variety, but $X$ may not be reduced.

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is sufficient to require that the union of all closed fibers
$$\bigcup_{s \in S \text{ closed}} X_s$$
is dense in $X$, since $f: X \to \mathbb A^1$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(0) \subset X$ is a closed subset.

*Example*. Suppose $X$ is of finite type over a field $k$, and denote $\pi: X \to S$ the given morphism. As closed points are mapped to closed points, any closed point $x \in X$ is contained in the closed fiber $X_{f(x)}$. Hence it is sufficient to show that the closed points of $X$ are dense in $X$. This is **Exercise II 3.14** in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.